# Cómo redondear las expresiones decimales en una consulta de SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select  substring(physical_name,1,1)  unidad, 
        round(((SUM(size)*1.0)/1024)*8,2) tamaño_MB
from    sys.master_files
where   database_id = (select DB_ID())
group by    substring(physical_name,1,1)
```

Con el sigueiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo quitar esos 4 "ceros" en la parte decimal después del 7, pensé que el `round()` me ayudaría:

2447715.07**0000**

Nota: Sin el `Round()`, me sale el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

... Sin embargo el número de decimales se sigue manteniendo a pesar del redondeo.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por tu ayuda Patricio, pero este es el código que buscaba (No era `numeric()` sino `decimal()`):

```
select  substring(physical_name,1,1)  unidad, 
        CONVERT(decimal(10,2),round(((SUM(size)*1.0)/1024)*8,2)) tamaño_MB
from    sys.master_files
where   database_id = (select DB_ID())
group by    substring(physical_name,1,1)
```

Y el resultado que esperaba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora solo tengo 2 decimales.

Comment: Perfecto, por las dudas te comento que NUMERIC y DECIMAL son sinónimos en SQL Server. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar el `convert` / `cast' para hacer algo así:

```
select  substring(physical_name,1,1)  unidad, 
        CONVERT(NUMERIC, 15,2),round(((SUM(size)*1.0)/1024)*8,2)) tamaño_MB
from    sys.master_files
where   database_id = (select DB_ID())
group by    substring(physical_name,1,1)
```

En este caso si quiere mantener una cifra razonable de dos decimales, lo puedes llevar sino a un `numeric(15,0)` para quitar todos, cuidado con el casteo a INT por que no funciona con número demasiado grandes, por ej:

```
select convert(int, 1234567890.12) --1.234.567.8
select convert(numeric(15,0), 1234567890.12) --1.234.567.890,00
```